# Zend Server CE messing with Apache?

Tags: zend-framework, apache

I am starting with a clean install of Fedora 15 on a VirtualBox VM and trying to install Zend Server CE.  To install, I adding the Zend repo to yum and ran:

```
sudo yum install zend-server-ce-php-5.3
```

The installation itself seemed to go very well.  I opened the browser at http://localhost:10081/ZendServer as directed.  After clicking through the license page and entering an administative password I get the error:

```
 Failed to access Web server. Please make sure that the Web server is running and listening to the correct port
```

The Applications, Rules Management and Administration tabs function properly but the Monitor and Server Setup tabs both display the above error.   It is a fact that the web server is not running, but when I try to rectify that I get another error:

```
$ sudo service httpd start
[sudo] Password for XXXXX:
Starting httpd (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

For what it's worth (not much, I'm guessing) here are the details the message refers to:

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/messages
....
Jan 17 17:24:18 M5 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 17 17:24:18 M5 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.

$ systemctl status httpd.service
httpd.service - LSB: start and stop Apache HTTP Server
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd)
      Active: failed since Tue, 17 Jan 2012 17:24:18 -0500; 3min 44s ago
     Process: 19500 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/httpd.service
```

The diagnostics don't seem very helpful.  I've tried various things, such as installing and starting httpd before installing Zend Server CE, reinstalling httpd (no good: unistalling it caused Zend to uninstall too).  The httpd config isn't causing the problem as the following output demonstrates:

```
$ /usr/sbin/apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Is this a know problem?  What's my next move?  Do I start putting debug statements in the control script to see what's failing?  I can do that, but I'm hoping someone out there has dealt with this problem and can give me a quick solution.

Comment: What does `apachectl configtest` show?

Comment: @Phil  Good question, but I just get "Syntax OK".  Will update my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get better information on the cause of the problem by invoking the `apachectl` script directly rather than using the `service`:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 220 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/zendserver_php.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/zend/lib/apache2/libphp5.so into server: /usr/local/zend/lib/apache2/libphp5.so: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

The syntax check on `httpd.conf` didn't catch this because it's not really a syntax error and it's not in `httpd.conf` either, but in the included `zendserver_php.conf`.  A quick search shows that this error is the result of `libphp5.so` violating one of the constraints that SELinux enforces.  SELinux is enabled by default in Fedora 15.

I don't like to reduce security, but that the only way I've seen this issue addressed.  So I disabled SELinux temporarily with the command

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

I also edited `/etc/selinux/config` and changed `SELINUX=enforced` to `SELINUX=disabled` so SELinux would stay disabled on reboot.  Now my web server starts without a hitch:

```
[mike@M5 ~]$ sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd (via systemctl):                            [  OK  ]
```

I would like to think someone in the Zend development community is working on this shared library issue.  Reducing security is not an acceptable work-around in a lot of cases.  If anybody has a better solution, I'd still like to know it.

Comment: Thank u mike.. I got te same problem. I have alreadyinstalled Apache on cent oS. then I got th error as u mentioned in ur question. Then i uninstlled apache and gave the command 'setenforce 0' and restarted the server..its done